# Web API 2 CORS attributes are not restricting CORS requests

Tags: cors, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to restrict CORS requests to a couple of specific origins, but the service is still serving requests to all origins, not just the ones I specify, and I need to restrict them.

WebApiConfig.cs file is as follows:

```
using System.Web.Http;    
using System.Web.Http.Cors;
using System.Web.Http.OData.Builder;
using System.Web.Http.OData.Extensions;
using TCApiOdata.Models;

namespace TCApiOdata
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

            //Entities here, no issues, they work fine.

            config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());
            // Web API routes


             var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://www.domain1.com,http://www.domain2.com", "*", "get", "DataServiceVersion, MaxDataServiceVersion");
             config.EnableCors(cors);

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }

    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong that is allowing requests from other origins besides those I specify? I should also note that I have no decorations on any controllers or actions... global scope only.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing your WebAPI using test method?  Webapi will return response for all requests even if you enabled CORS.  The thing is if Webapi request origin header value not matching to allowed origins in CORS the response will not have origin header so the browser security will not allowing to show response. If you check with fiddler you can see the difference. So CORS will be handled by Browser security not in Webapi.

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix, at least for Web Api hosted on an Azure App Service, as mine is.

First, open the App Service for the Web Api site in the Azure portal. If you go to the CORS settings (under "API" section), you can specify the allowed origins and Azure does indeed enforce allowed origins. You can also simply put a * to allow all origins.